# How to get Doctrine 2 to return an entity instead of a proxy

Tags: doctrine-orm, deep-copy

I'm trying to implement deep copy functionality using Doctrine 2, and I almost have it except for a method on one of my entities that attempts to strip out certain records from an association before returning the collection.

The problem is that when I call getRoofAreas() below, I get an array of Proxy objects, which my deep copy code doesn't like:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Entities\QuotingRoofAreas", mappedBy="customerId", cascade={"persist"})
 * @OrderBy({"areaIndex" = "ASC"})
 */

private $roofAreas;

public function getRoofAreas() {
    $em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
    $q = $em->createQuery("select ra from \Entities\QuotingRoofAreas ra where ra.dateDeleted IS NULL and ra.customerId = " . $this->getId());
    return $q->getResult();
}
```

but if I were to change this to:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Entities\QuotingRoofAreas", mappedBy="customerId", cascade={"persist"})
 * @OrderBy({"areaIndex" = "ASC"})
 */

private $roofAreas;

public function getRoofAreas() {
    return $roofAreas;
}
```

then it would return a persistent collection which, when iterated through, would get me Entity objects, which is what I want. The latter approach doesn't strip out deleted roof areas, which is a must for my use case.

Is there a way to get the Entity object for a Proxy object?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide

Comment: Did you try Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT?

Comment: $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM CmsUser u');
$users = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);

Answer (score 0):

Change your results method

```
return $q->getArrayResult();
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration