# Doctrine2: How to fetch pure entity, not a proxy?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Is it possible to fetch an already cached entity in Doctrine2 in it's pure form?

Whenever I try to fetch it using `find()` or event using the QueryBuilder, it results in a Proxy class, which is impossible to properly store and then wakeup in a Session.

I am using the entity as an User identity, which I would like to persist in the Session, but it seems, that the adapter can't really wake up proxies.

Any ideas?

I've tried `find()` from the repository, the query builder and even `refresh()` after the entity is fetched with no success.

Oh, and as I know about the EAGER fetch method, I'm not really sure it's usable in this case and how, since there are no relations taking place, and the proxy actually comes from Doctrines cache, or so I believe.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168963/how-to-get-doctrine-2-to-return-an-entity-instead-of-a-proxy

Comment: No, Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT did not work and the getArrayResult() isn't a solution either, because that would return an array, not an entity.

Comment: Just realised, Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT is the default value of getResult() in Doctrine 2.4 (That I'm using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find() never returns a proxy object, you have probably made a mistake somewhere.

Find() always returns an object of your entity class, whose **relations** will be proxy objects. If you want the relations to be not proxies, you will have to eager load them, either with DQL:

```
SELECT e, r FROM Enity e JOIN e.relation r
```

Or, by specifying the relation to be always eager loaded in your mapping, yaml example:

```
oneToMany:
    phonenumbers:
      targetEntity: Phonenumber
      mappedBy: user
      fetch: EAGER
```